# How do I get an Intel alc 880 analog sound card working on an Asus A6V?

Tags: 11.10, sound, hda-intel

I have an Asus A6V with Ubuntu 11.10 (32 bit). I don't find the drivers installed for Hda intel ALC 880 Analog and Digital. When I go into System Settings  and click on Sound (in the Hardware category), I should be able to select and enable the USB headphones/speakers in te Output tab. But I can't do that. There isn't any drivers installed.
What I should ?

Bye-bye

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!